# Every element gets focus in ie when I click on them in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is what you see after loading the page and scrolling down a bit.

[image]

Each element I click on gets focus.

[image]

I was wondering how I could stop this happening, could it be to do with tabindex?

This happens with every element on the screen - I was looking for a fix that doesn't involve me giving every element (bar the anchors that I have added) a outline none style.

Comment: try adding `outline:none` to the style of whatever you don't want the dotted lines on

Comment: @Pete It happens on every element on the page - including the page itself when you load it.

Comment: Which page are we talking about?